# How to create a Back Stack without TaskStackBuilder (pre 2.3)

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-support-library

When launching my app from a notification, I need to create a synthetic back stack since the target screen is several steps into the app navigation.  How can I do this without using TaskStackBuilder which is only supported as far back as Android 2.3?

**More Info:**
I have a single activity app that uses a separate fragment for each screen. So I use fragment transactions to change screens.  I'm currently using multiple back-to-back transactions to accomplish this, but it seems like there's probably a cleaner way.

Comment: Does *several steps into the app navigation* mean `Activity` navigation or changes to `View`s (like via a `ViewSwitcher`)?

Comment: I have a single activity app that uses a separate fragment for each screen.  So I use fragment transactions to change screens.

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using multiple fragment transactions passing 0's for the first two parameters of the setCustomAnimations methods.  Those two parameters are for the fading in transitions, so setting them to 0 causes the fragment transaction to complete immediately with no animation.

```
//first fragment
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).setCustomAnimations(0, 0, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right).replace(R.id.targetFrame, new Frag1(), "Frag1").commit();
getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

//second fragment
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).setCustomAnimations(0, 0, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right).replace(R.id.targetFrame, new Frag2(), "Frag2").commit();
getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

//add as many fragments as you like in this manner
```